# mysite personal documents

Tags: sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2010

Is there a way to provide a direct link to a person's personal docs in their mysite? I know th url looks like this for a particular user today: url:245523/personal/userid/default.aspx. Is there a way to provide a common link for every user?

Answer (score 0):

navigate to their personal docs (they must have set proper permissions themselves) and copy that URL.

The URL you listed here is do their web page.